# Три видео ютуб в строку

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать три видео в одну строку с использованием этого скрипта:

```
<div onclick="$(this).replaceWith('<iframe width=\'100%\' height=\'364\' src=\'http://www.youtube.com/embed/w-7rVHZUeLE?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0\' frameborder=\'0\' allowfullscreen></iframe><br/>');"><img src="http://clubsar.ru/assets/templates/turfirma/main-video.jpg" width="100%"/></div>
```

Нужно чтобы три видео были в одну строку по центру (скрипт заглушка).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Решение с использованием youtube js api - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kison/mgcpt7at/5/)

**html part**

```
 <div class="inline-videos">
        <div class="controls">
          <div id="show-videos"><img src="http://clubsar.ru/assets/templates/turfirma/main-video.jpg" width="100%"/></div>
        </div>

        <!-- video one -->
        <div class="inline-video">
            <div id="video1"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- video one -->
        <div class="inline-video">
            <div id="video2"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- video one -->
        <div class="inline-video">
            <div id="video3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**css part**

```
.inline-video {  
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
}

#show-videos {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**js part**

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player,
    videoId = "w-7rVHZUeLE";

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log("Youtube api ready!");
}

function initPlayer(containerId, videoId) {
    new YT.Player(containerId, {
        height: '200',
        width: '250',
        videoId: videoId,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}            

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}            

$(function(){
    console.log("dom ready");
      $("#show-videos").on('click', function(){
        $(this).hide();
        initPlayer("video1", "w-7rVHZUeLE");
        initPlayer("video2", "w-7rVHZUeLE");
        initPlayer("video3", "w-7rVHZUeLE");
    });
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за пояснение кодом! только вопрос теперь в другом - надо создать фаил и записать с расширением  js part в корне сайта - верно? код html part - вставлять в желаемое место на сайте? А вот теперь что делать или куда вставлять этот код css part? Извините если что - за мою не опытность!

Comment: html вставляете в код вашей страницы, с css и js тоже можете поступить аналогично, только стили нужно обернуть в тег <style>код</style>, а скрипты в тег <script>код</script>. Еще есть вариант с выносом стилей и скриптов в отдельные файлы. Стили будут к примеру в styles.css, скрипты в scripts.js, затем подключаете эти файлы в html кроме того не забудьте, что вам нужно подключить jQuery.

Comment: Возможно jQuery уже подключен так как в вашем вопросе он используется.

Comment: Да, еще момент, js код нужно добавить либо в перед закрывающим тегом body либо обернуть в конструкцию jquery dom ready

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Просто таких сейчас мало кто помогают по факту - мое уважение и почтение к тем кто еще способен правильно подсказать и расписать - спасибо что такие существуют! Только остался малый вопрос по теме - есть сайт https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery - там как раз под ютуб фаил - его можно использовать или совместно надо с jQuery?

Comment: developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery это cdn, т.е если вы добавите jquery таким образом <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>, то больше ничего делать касательно подключения jquery не нужно он будет загружен с google серверов.